# Which is the reference 16S rRNA?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, microbiology, sequence-analysis, primer

Recently, I've stumbled upon a fact, which hasn't bothered me for many years. The fact is that all universal 16S primers are written as "[FR][0-9]+" (in regex notation), that is they have a position with respect to a reference. I've read through many papers, wherein these primers were introduced, and most of the time the authors say nothing but "E. coli 16S". Anyway, in [one case](http://www.pnas.org/content/suppl/2009/11/30/0907926106.DCSupplemental/ST1_PDF.pdf) I've found that it is in fact the reference K12 E. coli. But the problem is that it has 7 distinct rRNA operons: rrnA, rrnB, rrnC, rrnD, rrnE, rrnF, rrnG. Do you have a reference showing a particular operon used for the 16S position notation?

**Edit**
[image]

Figure 2. Hypervariable regions within the 16S rRNA gene in Pseudomonas . The plotted line reflects fluctuations in variability amongst aligned 16S rRNA gene sequences of 79 Pseudomonas type strains... ([Bodilis et al., 2012](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0035647))

Comment: Are you sure they differ in sequence at the primer? The sequences of the structural parts of the genes are apparently almost identical. Have you checked GenBank?

Comment: @David I haven't checked that myself, but here is a relevant reference `... or the same strain may have multiple copies of the 16S rRNA gene that differ by 5% for some regions (such as Escherichia coli K12 [12])...` [(Nguyen et al., 2016)](https://www.nature.com/articles/npjbiofilms20164)

Comment: @David while the primers are indeed located in short conservative regions between hypervariable regions, the latter are extremely variable. I've added a figure depicting this variation across several *Pseudomonas* strains. Therefore, it doesn't matter, whether the primers are located in conservative regions or not, what's important is that they target regions that can vary in both sequence and length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly point out, designing an optimal primer pair for 16S-rRNA sequencing is a tricky affair because even the less-variable regions are not same between different strains and species. [Sambo et al (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1186/s12859-018-2360-6) have even developed a bioinformatics software for optimal design of primers for 16S-rRNA sequencing for multiple bacteria.

> We propose here a computational method for optimizing the choice of
>   primer sets, based on multi-objective optimization, which
>   simultaneously: 1) maximizes efficiency and specificity of target
>   amplification; 2) **maximizes the number of different bacterial 16S
>   sequences matched by at least one primer**; 3) minimizes the differences
>   in the number of primers matching each bacterial 16S sequence. Our
>   algorithm can be applied to any desired amplicon length without
>   affecting computational performance.

There is diversity in the 16S-rRNA genes within the same species i.e. the different copies are not exact duplicates ([Větrovský & Baldrian, 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3583900/)).

> [image]
>   <sub>Větrovský & Baldrian (2013)</sub>

Interestingly, the different rRNA operons in *E.coli* have different promoters and are even differentially expressed during stress conditions ([Kurylo et al., 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30282032)).

However, [Kitahara et al. (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1213609109) found that 16S-rRNA genes isolated from soil samples, in place of the original *E.coli* gene, could support its growth. In other words *E.coli* is highly robust to mutations in its 16S-rRNA.

> After counterselection, ∼200 clones of KT103-derivatives (carrying
>   pRB103 whose 16S rRNA gene was substituted with foreign genes) were
>   obtained, from which 33 nonredundant 16S rRNA genes (A01–H03) were
>   identified. Through multiple alignment of E. coli 16S rRNA and our
>   metagenomically retrieved 16S rRNA sequences, it was found that at
>   least 628 (40.7%) of the 1,542 nucleotides were variable, indicating
>   marked mutational robustness of the 16S rRNA. Strikingly, the
>   functional 16S rRNA sequences (except A10 and F02, which were 99.0%
>   identical to E. coli 16S rRNA) obtained in this study showed only
>   80.9–89.3% identity to E. coli 16S rRNA, which was well below the value reported thus far (Proteus vulgaris 16S rRNA, 94% identity to E.
>   coli 16S rRNA)

---

For your question

> *But the problem is that it has 7 distinct rRNA operons: rrnA, rrnB,
>   rrnC, rrnD, rrnE, rrnF, rrnG. Do you have a reference showing a
>   particular operon used for the 16S position notation?*

I don't think any one of them is considered the reference. The [complete *E.coli* 16S-rRNA sequence reported in NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/J01859) seems to consider a "consensus" of different reported sequences:

> [5], [7] contain updated sequence data for the original work by the
>   same laboratory [4]. There were too many discrepancies between [4] and
>   [5], [7] to list each revision in our sites table. The sequence shown
>   is from [7]. [4], [5], [7] point to a number of cistron
>   heterogeneities. There is uncertainty, however, with regard to
>   assigning these various heterogeneities to specific cistrons. The RNA
>   method used by [4], [5], [7] gives the average of all the cistrons
>   present in the cell [7]. The heterogeneities are classified by their
>   relative proportions into major, minor and undetermined species. The
>   sequence shown corresponds to the major species. The heterogeneities
>   were annotated as variations in the sites table. It is not known which
>   of the residues 'c' (base 633) or 'a' (base 641) undergoes a deletion,
>   giving rise to the minor component 'atctg'. [7] suggests the existence
>   of one or two mutated cistrons among the known seven cistrons of
>   ribosomal RNA. **With the exception of a single base deletion, this
>   sequence is identical to the current 16S rDNA sequence for the E.coli
>   rRNB gene.**

The NCBI page also lists different polymorphisms and base modifications in the 16S-rRNA within and between different strains/"species".

NCBI has several partial sequences as well. When I checked for *P.aeruginosa* and *B.subtilis*, I could find only one or two complete sequences (rest were partial). Moreover, each entry indicated the strain that it was obtained from. Therefore I assume there is no single reference sequence.

I guess that people do consider the different variants while doing phylogenetic analysis (or simply just look for conserved "signature" sequences for a given species). I am sure that there are computational algorithms for doing the classification in an optimal manner (see [Chatellier et al., 2014](https://dx.doi.org/10.1099/jmm.0.074377-0)). Since, I don't have an expertise in this area I cannot say anything conclusively about the routine practice. In fact there is still ongoing research in improving the analysis (for example, [Yang et al., 2016](https://doi.org/10.1186/s12859-016-0992-y) and [Sambo et al., 2018](https://doi.org/10.1186/s12859-018-2360-6)).

Comment: While I don't have access to the original paper by Ehresmann et al. (1972) that seems to be the source of that sequence, the preview does suggest that their methodology can only produce a consensus sequence.